# Generate Express Routes Dynamically from MongoDB Data which changes every few Minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js, mean-stack

I want to create a web page that dynamically renders data from mongoDB. 
I am crawling articles on the internet and then saving data related to that in a MongoDB.
Now I want to create dynamic routes within express (e.g. page/:word), where word is a word taken from the crawled articles. If you use that route you get some information and statistics about the word (e.g. when it's used most)
The Problem I am having now is, that once i started my NodeJS Express Server the routes aren't updatet because once the data is loaded from the MongoDB it's not updatet later, when there is for example a new word in the database. 
Is there any way to update these routes dynamically when I change data in the MongoDB ? 
Btw: I am Using Handlebars to render the webpage, would all of that be easier with Angular ? 
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You could check the database for each request, to see if the word can be found in the database:

```
app.get('/page/:word', (req, res) => {
  collection.find({ word : req.params.word }).toArray().then(results => {
    if (results.length) {
      ...word found...
    } else {
      ...word not found...
    }
  });
});
```